# Delay When Closing `:terminal` Window

Tags: neovim, terminal, performance, windows

Long story, short.... Everything's fine on my MacBook, but I have an issue in Neovim 0.9.1 on Windows 10. I see this behavior when

1. starting `nvim` from the usual shells - Command Prompt (cmd.exe), Powershell, and Git Bash;
2. in their default console programs and Windows Terminal; and
3. with all three values of `:set shell` - `cmd.exe`, `pwsh`, and `bash`.

I thought it was a bug in one of the plugins I use, but by process of elimination, I now think the issue is in vanilla Neovim.

The problem is: when closing a `:terminal` window, there is a delay of 4 seconds before it responds. I can shorten the delay by pressing a key within that 4 seconds. The delay seems to be related to the `'updatetime'` setting, whose default is 4000ms. Setting it to 1000, reduces the wait time to 1 second, which seems to substantiate my claim. However, I don't see how closing a terminal window should be related to that setting, so I'm reluctant to change it.

The steps to reproduce the issue are below. Has anyone else seen this and know what's happening? Should I report this to the neovim github repo? I wanted to ask this here before I added to their already large backlog of issues.

```
$ nvim -u NONE
:set updatetime?    " prints 4000
:terminal
exit                # 4-second delay before terminal window closes
:set updatetime=1000
:terminal
exit                # 1-second delay before terminal window closes
```

#### Update

Git ships with its own copy of vim, version 9.0 in my case, which you can run inside of the Git Bash window. I don't see this issue there. So this is looking like a Neovim-only issue.

Comment: I think [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) contains some other invocations besides `-u NONE` that might help reduce the problem (ex: a mapping on Escape or Ctrl-D might cause some weirdness? plugins?)

Comment: Thanks for the reference; there was a lot of new information there. Unfortunately, none of those suggestions helped narrow anything down. `-u NONE` seems to be the correct option to use for 'out-of-the-box' Neovim. `:scriptnames` shows nothing, there are only two autocommands: `nvim_cmdwin CmdWinEnter` and `nvim_terminal  BufReadCmd`, and `:map` shows only `x #`, `x *`, `n &`, `n Y`, and `n <C-L>`. Still seeing the same issue.

Comment: Time for a bug report, maybe?

Comment: Perhaps. I'll need to do some more investigation, and organize my results first. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I submitted the following bug report after reproducing this: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/27615

Comment: Thanks, Amin! I was just getting ready to create the issue, when I saw that you'd already done so. Even better is that it's been fixed so quickly.